# How can I update Code of AWS Lambda via command line?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Currently, when I update my Lambda function, I

1. Open https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/ in a browser and navigate to the lambda function
2. Choose 'Code entry type: Upload a file from Amazon S3'
3. Enter the S3 URL I got before from uploading it via command line `aws s3 cp [local] [bucket]`

Is there a way to do all of this via command line?

Answer (score 7):

```
$ aws lambda update-function-code \
    --function-name your-lambda-name \
    --s3-bucket your-bucket \
    --s3-key your-key
```

See [update-function-code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html) of the `aws` command line program.

Comment: i think if we are pointing towards s3 bucket no need to use --zip-file